# How to render API response into a tabular form in react js

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios

I'm trying to create a react app in which based on the Form inputs it calls API and provide the response in json, where i want this json to be rendered in tabular format. But table shouldn't displayed during initial page load, it should only display after API fetch. Please suggest any ways to achieve this via react js.

Below is my code:

APP.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Axios from "axios";import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import Recipe from "./components/Recipe";
import Alert from "./components/Alert";

function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState("");

  const url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`;

  const getData = async () => {
    if (query !== "") {
      const result = await Axios.get(url);
      if (!result.data.more) {
        return setAlert("No food with such name");
      }
      console.log(result);
      setRecipes(result.data.hits);
      setQuery("");
      setAlert("");
    } else {
      setAlert("Please fill the form");
    }
  };

  const onChange = e => setQuery(e.target.value);

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    getData();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Food Searching App</h1>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="search-form">
        {alert !== "" && <Alert alert={alert} />}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="query"
          onChange={onChange}
          value={query}
          autoComplete="off"
          placeholder="Search Food"
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
      </form>
      <div className="recipes">
        {recipes !== [] &&
          recipes.map(recipe => <Recipe key={uuidv4()} recipe={recipe} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Defining Table in above return() shows Form with table also.(Table has to be showed only after API call successful and should contain API data) Any suggestion or any resource material to refer is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert this section into the following

```
  <div className="recipes">
    {
      recipes.length > 0 
      ? <table>
          <tr>
            {
              recipes.map(recipe => <Recipe key={uuidv4()} recipe={recipe} />)
            }
          </tr>
        </table>
       : null
    }
  </div>
```

The table would be rendered only upon receiving the response.

Comment: Thank you Sridhar for the suggestion, apparently it's throwing new err0r as "Error: 
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`."

Comment: I was supposed to use <table> instead of <Table>. Can you try now? ( I have edited my changes)